# Low level C/C++ networking concepts for real-time programming?

Tags: c++, c, networking, real-time

I'm rather interested in real-time programming and whilst I feel I know a decent amount regarding algorithms and data structures, I dont feel I know much about how to get the data into the computer as quick as possible in order to process.

Would any of you be so kind as to point me to topics I could google for, in order to help me? Most of my C books dont really touch on networking and my C++ books treat networking as a basic topic. For example, I wouldnt have much problem creating a UDP connection between two computers, but in what ways can you make the connection the most efficient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Networking AFAIK is a platform dependent thing.  With Windows, you have [WinSock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741416%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Others I don't recall at the moment.  That should give you a direction to start in.

Comment: Actually the difference between WinSockets and Linux network sockets are minimal. If you learn one the other is almost identical.

Comment: Your question doesn't really say were you are going with this.  Are you looking for something like Beej's Guide to networking?  Real time as in hard real time (i.e. Industrial Automation Controls) or soft real time as in video games, and streaming video?

Comment: Real-time networking requires special networking hardware.  The kind that isn't going to get bogged down by collisions like Ethernet or the unpredictable behavior of routers.  Field busses used in industrial automation would be an example.  UDP certainly doesn't apply, the protocols are custom.  Books don't talk about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just so you know: **[Real Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)** means that you have a time constraint on your application, it doesn't necessarily mean "fast" or "quick" or "efficient". Real-time operation can take 1 hour, but it will be real time as long as it is restricted to last no more than 1 hour.

As to the networking - it by itself is not real time as you cannot control the other side. There are various "real-time" protocols that handle this limitation in various ways (because you have time constraints on applications like clock syncing, video/audio streaming, etc), so you need to dig into these particular protocols - per need. One example is the [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol). You can see that it's fairly complicated, not just a UDP message written in an "efficient" way.

General network programming is system dependent, but you can start with [UNIX networking](http://www.hiraeth.com/alan/tutorials/courses/tcpip.html) and the [BSD Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) to get the idea.

Comment: "Real-time" can also simply mean "streaming", with no actual constraint.  Generally not in the case of networking though.

Comment: @Ben Shouldn't we in general distinguish between soft and hard real-time systems? Ie streaming as a typical scenario for a soft rt system where it's preferable to reach deadlines, but not of utter importance, contrary to some hard rt systems where missing a deadline may have catastrophic (eg an ABS) effects? About networking being be definition not real-time: I object, there are systems that guarantee a max. reaction time for high priority messages - although that probably depends how you define "networking".

Comment: @Voo: I didn't mean that networking isn't real-time, I meant that "real-time" in the case of networking almost never merely means streaming, it's far more often dealing with deadlines than in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you learn about networking in the Unix environment. Look for books on "Unix network programming". It deals with very low level stuff. You would use both POSIX spec and ANSI/ISO C spec to write network programs. Both specs have entwined history, so it might be a little confusing in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about networking, I saved this book to read some day [Internetworking with TCP/IP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130183806)